# Google Kickstart 2020 Round A 2020 Wrong Answer

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was trying to solve this problem from Google Kickstart: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ffc7/00000000001d3f56#problem

For some reason, it succeeds on the sample set, but fails on test set 1.
I have tried many test Cases and the code works properly for all of them. Whats wrong with my code?

```
int main() {
    int T;
    std::cin >> T;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        int N, B;
        std::cin >> N >> B;
        int* set = new int[N];
        
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            std::cin >> set[j];
        }
        std::sort(set, set + N);

        int monLeft = B;
        int max = 0;
        while (max < T) {
            monLeft -= set[max];
            if (monLeft < 0) break;
            max++;
        }

        std::cout << "Case #" << i + 1 << ": " << max << std::endl; 
        delete set;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm fairly sure delete set; is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
while (max < T) {
```

is wrong. The limit should be the number of horses, which is `N`. It should be

```
while (max < N) {
```